# Modal box for options in Selectize.js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

Is it possible to modify selectize.js? Instead of having a dropdown it will open a modal box for its options ?  I am thinking of having a onfocus event then it will open that modal but prevent the dropdown. I'm just not sure how I can achieve it. and How I can populate the selectize once the modal options have been saved

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to customize a code library because you will not be able to upgrade to the next version.  You are better off rolling your own solution using js and css.  Actually making modal boxes is not that difficult, you just need to float a div at a higher z-index than the rest of the page, then put a transparent layer behind it to keep the user from clicking through to the background page.  Here is some sample css and html I use to float a modal.

css

```
.BDT_Dialog_Layer {
position: absolute;
display: table;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 99%;
width: 99%;
}
.BDT_Dialog_Center {
position:fixed;
top:30%;
width:100%;
}
.BDT_Dialog_Decoration {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ffffff;
display: table;    
/* --    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF'    , endColorstr='#BBBBBB');
background-image: -webkit-gradient(  linear,  left top,  left bottom,  color-stop(0.1, #FFFFFF),  color-stop(1, #BBBBBB)  );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(  center top,  #FFFFFF 10%,  #BBBBBB 100%  ); -- */
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-khtml-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #666666, 0 1px 4px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #666666, 0 1px 4px #000000;
-khtml-box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #666666, 0 1px 4px #000000;
box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #666666, 0 1px 4px #000000;   
}
```

html

```
<div id="dialogLayer" class="BDT_Dialog_Layer">
    <div class="BDT_Dialog_Center">
        <div class="BDT_Dialog_Decoration">                    
            My stuff                         
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the blocking layer css

```
div.BlockInteractionWithPage {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* filter:alpha for IE8 and earlier */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
}
```